What has changed in Windows 10 in the last month that could cause Zone.Identifier files to be created?
I run Windows 10 in a Virtualbox VM for the sole purpose of using a scanning application. At some point in the last month, something changed which means the scanned files now have accompanying Zone.Identifier files.
I know what these files are thanks to this question (they are alternate data streams), and I guess they are being created because the folder in question is a Virtualbox shared folder backed by a non-NTFS filesystem. What I cannot explain is why these files are being created now, but weren't the last time I used the scanner (nor ever before in the nearly 10 years that I've been using this VM for this purpose).
The contents of the files are:
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3

which, for what it's worth, seems to be incorrect, as according to this document zone 3 is the internet zone, but these files were created locally.
Aside from scanning, the only other thing this VM does is run Windows Update. Did something change in a recent update that has caused these files to start being created?
Update: Shortly after posting this question I restarted the VM which applied an update, and now I cannot reproduce this. The updates that were installed today were KB5046613 and KB5046542.
The previous update, installed just over two weeks ago, was KB5044273.

If you can recreate it happening, run Process Monitor (Sysinternals(, you should see the Zone.Identifier ADS being written by a process.  What process is it and what does the stack look like? Ideally you can get at least public symbols to help resolve the functions names to help.  In Process Monitor, create a filter for path ends with  Zone.Identifier and operation is WriteFile.  Under the Filter menu you can drop filtered events. As soon as you see it being written, what does the stack look like?

What changed in Windows 10? Nothing has changed in Windows 10 that could explain this behavior.

What scanning application? Is there any chance it's sending the scans to the cloud and back for some reason? What happens if you scan something while disconnected from the internet?

@HelpingHand. Sorry, I can no longer reproduce this following an update applied while rebooting. I've updated the question with the KBs that got installed.

@SteveRindsberg: Fujitsu ScanSnap. It runs fine with no internet connection and it's never needed an online account or given any indication that it would like to talk to any server.

@jl6 OK, I use ScanSnap here, also under Win10, though on hardware, not a VM. In any case, I've never seen any suggestion that it wants to contact anything over the internet. Glad to hear your update sorted the problem, whatever it might have been.
